# dot product and setting element of matrix opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, product

I'm using the opencv library on a ubuntu build with Qt Creator and I have the following problem. I am tryng to calculate the dot product of a vector and the RGB values within an image, I then want to return these values to a separate matrix which holds the result. After this operation I then want to subtract this matrix from another, however, to ensure the matrix is in the correct data type I use the convertTo() function and found that this throws the segmentation fault.

It appears to be something to do with element writing, if I change the input from the dot product to a predefined value it works.

I have spent a few hours trying to get this running and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
int x,y;
float Xn = 0.95;
float Zn = 1.089;

//destination matrix
Mat XYZ_mat(10, 10, CV_32FC3, Scalar(1.0,1.0,1.0));

//source matrix
Mat BGR_mat(10, 10, CV_32FC3, Scalar(1.0,1.0,1.0));


//source vectors
float LAB_mult_x[3][1] ={0.4, 0.2, 0.01};
Mat LAB_Mult_x(3, 1, CV_32FC1, LAB_mult_x);

float LAB_mult_y[3][1] ={0.35, 0.71, 0.11};
Mat LAB_Mult_y(3, 1, CV_32FC1, LAB_mult_y);

float LAB_mult_z[3][1] ={0.18, 0.07, 0.95};
Mat LAB_Mult_z(3, 1, CV_32FC1, LAB_mult_z);


for (x=0;x<=XYZ_mat.rows;x++){
    for (y=0; y<=XYZ_mat.cols;y++){

        //extacts BGR vals from image
        Vec3f temp1 = BGR_mat.at<Vec3b>(x,y);
        temp2 = Mat(temp3);

        XYZ_mat.at<Vec3b>(x,y)[0] = float(temp2.dot(LAB_Mult_x)/Xn);
        XYZ_mat.at<Vec3b>(x,y)[1] = float(temp2.dot(LAB_Mult_y));
        XYZ_mat.at<Vec3b>(x,y)[2] = float(temp2.dot(LAB_Mult_z)/Zn);

}
}

//segmentation fault is thrown here
XYZ_mat.convertTo(XYZ_mat,CV_32FC3);
```

Many thanks

Laurence

Comment: Use `<` instead of `<=` in the for loop condition.

Comment: Completely overlooked that! thanks, you saved me spending another few hours